# How to locally load a finetuned LLAMA2 model that currently saved to my local disk in safe tensor format

Tags: nlp, large-language-model, huggingface, llama

I am new to working with LLMs. I have a finetuned LLAMA2 model in safe tensor format saved to my local disk. I want to load my model locally by running a python notebook.

I have tried googling, and I find many examples on loading Stable diffusion models but noting much on loading LLAMA models.